# Azure Devops pipeline set up issue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set up an Azure devops pipeline to build and deploy the Hybris Application on the servers.
I have been able to install the agent on the server where the build/Packaging needs to happen and the agent is showing up in the agent pool and I have added build task as well to the pipeline .As soon as i run the pipeline i keep getting the below error -

> ### [error]No agent found in pool  which satisfies the specified demands:
>
> ```
>  ant
>  Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.115.0
> ```

I am unable to figure out the reason for the error message and the build keeps failing.Can anyone point out what am i missing.

Comment: Can you add your build tasks into the question?

Comment: @user964819 Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

I think, your build task uses the ant to build or deploy changes. You have to:

1. Install the latest version of the ant.
2. Restart your build agent to add your new software into [capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities).

[image]

Comment: You don't need to unregister an agent after adding a new capability. Simply restarting the agent service will cause it to enumerate and capture new capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue , there's possibility that your self-hosted agent lacks certain capabilities necessary to build and deploy a Hybrid Application.

In many cases, after you deploy an agent, you'll need to install software or utilities. Generally you should install on your agents whatever software and tools you use on your development machine.

For example, if your build includes the npm task, then the build won't run unless there's a build agent in the pool that has npm installed.

You need to check your agent's  capabilities and add missing capabilities as user-defined capabilities.

[image]

After you install new software on an agent, you must restart the agent for the new capability to show up in the pool so that the build can run.

In addition , you could also check if there are Demands in your pipeline.

[image]